# Check for Number Order in Arbitrarily Long String

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to match a string that has an arbitrary length against a list of phone numbers?  I've seen phone number validation regex, I'm more looking to match a string if it has the numbers supplied, in that order.

Say something like this:

```
regexStr = /5542215555/gi

// All these strings should pass
phoneNums = [
  '(554) 221-5555'
  '5542215555x645115',
  '554-221-5555',
  '55-422155-55',
  'abc 554 def 221 ghi 5555'
]

// These would fail, due to numbers not present / not in order
nonMatches = [
  '(554) 331-5555'
  '5542205555x645115',
  '554-221-4444',
  '554-221-222-4444',
  'abc 554 def 112 ghi 5555'
]
```

I don't necessarily care that there are a number of characters between the numbers or what the characters are, I just want to make sure the numbers in the string has all of the numbers in the correct order.

I've not been able to find a question that matches this use-case, but reading around I believe a [branch reset group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) might be the ticket for what I'm looking for, though the implementation looks very... involved.  In addition to that, I don't believe that JS handles them correctly judging by that page's examples of branch reset groups.

Is this possible / feasible in JS with its implementation of Regex?

Comment: it looks like you would just add `.*` between each group of 3-4 numbers.

Comment: All the pass and fail examples seem to be the same or same format.

Comment: @njzk2 I'll want to include any groups of numbers, not just 3-4.  I'd also want to ensure that `554 this_should_make_the_check_fail_1122 221 5555`

@j08691 They have different numbers, although the formats picked were just at random.  I'll add some other examples to the OP.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica why should this make the test fail? because of the extra digits?

Comment: @njzk2 Yeah, basically.  I want to make sure the characters between the ones I'm looking for are only non-digits, ensuring all numbers are in their correct order (without any scrambled in the middle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure

```
/5\D*5\D*4\D*2\D*2\D*1\D*5\D*5\D*5\D*5/gi
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gD4xV5/2)

Or if you want something less sloppy : [`/5\D{0,3}5\D{0,3}4\D{0,5}2\D{0,3}2\D{0,3}1\D{0,5}5\D{0,3}5\D{0,3}5\D{0,3}5/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/gD4xV5/5)

Comment: That's probably the best approach, but you should use `\D*` instead of `.*`.

Comment: @AlanMoore Yep, just got to that conclusion myself.  A fitting example that matches above would be something like `/5[\D]*5[\D]*4[\D]*2[\D]*2[\D]*1[\D]*5[\D]*5[\D]*5[\D]*5/gi`